# Delphi hiding a form: Is there a difference between Form.Hide and Form.Visible:=False?

Tags: delphi, forms, hide, visible

I'm looking through two copies of code and in one I have myForm.Hide and another I have myForm.Visible := False.  I can't remember why I changed this, if one was a bug fix or whether there is any difference at all.

Comment: You don't have to remember, just ask the version control for a log about that particular file.  The comment would include a link to your bug tracker, just in case. :)

Comment: Do you have the VCL source code in your version of Delphi?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference for `Hide`.  The VCL code is:

```
procedure TCustomForm.Hide;
begin
  Visible := False;
end;
```

But `Show` is a bit different:

```
procedure TCustomForm.Show;
begin
  Visible := True;
  BringToFront;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how old your Delphi code is and how far back it goes.  Form.Hide at one time (Win95/2000) would hide the form AND its taskbar icon - the other would not.  Of course, there was some patches, etc to fix issues with Delphi and certain video cards/color palettes would require you to consider how you wanted to hide forms. (man I am showing my age). I've seen code that would set the form Left to a big negative number just to hide the form off the screen cause of issues with hardware (Delphi 1-3 was really hardware sensitive)

Also, around Delphi 3/4 there was a memory leak using minimize instead of hide in MDI applications (so we used PAgecontrol with form docking over MDI Forms).  So, if you are looking at very old code, then those things matter.  If you are compiling on Delphi 6 or better, then there is really no difference.

Comment: I find your first paragraph a little hard to believe. I don't remember anything like that. I'd be astounded if TCustomForm.Hide was ever different from Visible := False. On the other hand, perhaps my brain has erased the painful memories and left just the happy ones!

Comment: Yeah, if I hadn't seen and had to code around it myself about 97/98 I wouldn't either!  Delphi 1 and 2 where horrible with memory and ran into all kind of problems.  Delphi 1 was 16-bit Win3.11 and Delphi 2 was first 32-bit version with a LOT of 16-bit stuff.  Just load Delphi 2 and set PC color to 16 colors and watch your programs not load - especially if they had grids on the forms!!

Comment: I used those versions too, I just don't remember quite so much pain!

Comment: Me neither! I remember a Delphi 1 application used in a bunch of win 31. laptops and desktops for a great amount of time, mo memories for that mentioned weird behavior!

Comment: Thanks MDV2000, luckily I'm using Delphi 6 (planning upgrade to XE soon)